# Kotlin: secondary constructor with this keyword

Tags: kotlin

```
data class DisjointSetNode<T>(var parent: DisjointSetNode<T>, var data: T, var rank: Int) {
constructor(data: T): this(parent = this, data = data, rank = 0)
```

I was wondering why I am getting an error saying that I cannot use the this keyword in the constructor call because I have not called the superclass constructor first. There is no superclass, and I want to make itself a parent. Any ideas of how I would go about doing this?

Comment: That's possibly a bad error message.  Nevertheless, `this` doesn't yet exist (the call to `this()` is effectively the thing that brings it into existence).

Comment: In this case `this` should probably be a whole another data class, one that doesn't have a `parent` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you can't calling `this` during calling another constructor by `this(...)`. you can take a look at [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7):

> It is a **compile-time** error for a constructor to **directly** or **indirectly** invoke itself through a series of one or more explicit constructor invocations involving **this**.

- **directly** means calling `this` in `this(...)` at the first statement,  e.g: `this(this);`.
- **indirectly** means calling its members during call `this(...)`, e.g:`this(parent)`.

but you can makes the *primary constructor* to a *secondary constructor* to achieve your way, for example:

```
data class DisjointSetNode<T>(var data: T, var rank: Int = 0) {
    var parent: DisjointSetNode<T> = this

    constructor(parent: DisjointSetNode<T>, data: T) : this(data = data){
        this.parent = parent
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reference `this` in this context because it is not yet defined.

You can however move `parent` to outside the constructor signature. e.g.:

```
data class DisjointSetNode<T>(var data: T, var rank: Int = 0) {
    var parent: DisjointSetNode<T> = this
}
```

Comment: So this should have the effect of when instantiating a DisjointSetNode having parent automatically equal to itself?

Comment: @user3338275 yes. There's an order of creation when you make a new class. The constructors come first, followed by the other content inside (including parent)